# Can't run gunicorn on port 80 while deploying django app on AWS EC2

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, gunicorn

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 instance in my EC2 AWS.

I can run `gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 myapp.wsgi`

but it fails to run at port 80

`gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:80 myapp.wsgi` --> Fails

I tried to follow this answer (I couldn't understand it though, whats deployment script ?) [Getting Gunicorn to run on port 80](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16225872/getting-gunicorn-to-run-on-port-80)

But it didn't work.

I also tried running it with elevated permission `sudo` in vain.
Error on running at port 80:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-39-159:~/jeequery$ gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:80 rubiks.wsgi
[2015-08-30 15:58:10 +0000] [6772] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.3.0
[2015-08-30 15:58:10 +0000] [6772] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2015-08-30 15:58:11 +0000] [6772] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2015-08-30 15:58:12 +0000] [6772] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2015-08-30 15:58:13 +0000] [6772] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2015-08-30 15:58:14 +0000] [6772] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2015-08-30 15:58:15 +0000] [6772] [ERROR] Can't connect to ('0.0.0.0', 80)
```

On running with `sudo` I get this error:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-39-159:~$ gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:80 rubiks.wsgi
[2015-08-30 16:48:09 +0000] [6943] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.3.0
[2015-08-30 16:48:09 +0000] [6943] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2015-08-30 16:48:10 +0000] [6943] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2015-08-30 16:48:11 +0000] [6943] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
^C[2015-08-30 16:48:12 +0000] [6943] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2015-08-30 16:48:13 +0000] [6943] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2015-08-30 16:48:14 +0000] [6943] [ERROR] Can't connect to ('0.0.0.0', 80)
ubuntu@ip-172-31-39-159:~$ ^C
ubuntu@ip-172-31-39-159:~$ sudo gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:80 rubiks.wsgi
[2015-08-30 16:48:21 +0000] [6947] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.3.0
[2015-08-30 16:48:21 +0000] [6947] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:80 (6947)
[2015-08-30 16:48:21 +0000] [6947] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2015-08-30 16:48:21 +0000] [6950] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 6950
[2015-08-30 16:48:21 +0000] [6950] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 507, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 118, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 355, in import_app
    __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named 'rubiks'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 507, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 118, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 355, in import_app
    __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named 'rubiks'
[2015-08-30 16:48:21 +0000] [6950] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 6950)
[2015-08-30 16:48:21 +0000] [6947] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2015-08-30 16:48:21 +0000] [6947] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

Comment: What do you mean by it fails? Elaborate more on the error please.

Comment: @beezz updated answer with error log

Comment: If with `sudo`, error is the same, check if you are not already running something on port 80. Apache or nginx etc.

Comment: @beezz  I ran sudo service nginx stop , but still I can see ngix welcome screen here: http://ec2-54-148-229-51.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com

Comment: I uninstalled nginx now , getting a different error with `sudo` (Updating error log in question)

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this at all? gunicorn isn't really suitable for exposing directly to the internet; usually you'd run it behind a reverse proxy. Since you already had nginx running, you should re-enable it and use it as it is meant to be.

Comment: @DanielRoseman : All I want to do is serve my django application on port 80. I read online while searching `gunicorn` is used widely (Even Heroku uses it for production purposes).
I tried basic `./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80 ` and failed.
How can  I serve my django application with `nginx` on port 80 ?
As you might have already guess, I am n00b and trying this for the first time, please bear with me .

Comment: As I said, you run nginx on port 80, and use it as a reverse proxy in front of gunicorn. Don't try and run gunicorn itself on port 80. The gunicorn docs have a full config example.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks. Got it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11443917/why-does-gunicorn-use-port-8000-8001-instead-of-80

Comment: I'd be very cautious believing that a specific WSGI server is the best just because someone else uses it. What WSGI server is best depends on your specific application. The gunicorn WSGI server with its default sync worker is a poor choice for mostly I/O bound applications especially in memory constrained environments, such as a PaaS, with fat Django web applications. This is because to achieve high concurrency, you need more processes which means more money to the hosting service as you will need to scale out quicker when you run out of memory. For I/O bound, threaded WSGI servers are better.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As suggested in comments, its not recommended  to run `gunicorn` on port `80`.

We instead run it on port greater than  `1024` (non privileged ports) and by reverse poxy request to port greater than `1014` running on `gunicorn`.

This can be done by editing `nginx` config file.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The questioner specifically mentions that he wants gunicorn to run on port 80. Your suggests using nginx as a reverse proxy and then running gunicorn on port 8000. What if we don't want to use nginx or any other reverse proxy server?

Answer (score 0):

**It seems that you have not added port 80 to your security groups..

Also you will have to use `sudo` before your command to access port 80

Hope this helps**